# ASP.NET Setup Authentication through Parameters.xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Web Application where part of my web.config file looks like below

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add value="NTLM" />
        <add value="Negotiate" />
      </providers>
    </windowsAuthentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

On the other hand, I have configured a Parameters.xml file (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment)   to define different settings depending on my environment along with different **<_APPNAME>.<_ENVIRONMENT>.SetParameters.xml** files.

I am trying to figure out how can I define different authentication settings through the Parameters.xml?

- On Environment A, I need to have **windowsAuthentication enabled="true"**
  (and anonymousAuthentication enabled="false")
- On Environment B, I need to have **anonymousAuthentication

  enabled="true"** (and windowsAuthentication enabled="false")

Answer (score 0):

At least for the AppSettings, you can use the configSource parameter.  I believe you can for other sections as well.

```
<security configSource="config\default.config" />
```

And when you deploy to the different environments, you can use web.config transforms (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<security configSource="config\envASettings.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```